# SQL Many-to-many relationship between 3 tables

Tags: sql, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following tables:

```
Users
 - user_id (PK)

Projects
 - project_id (PK)

Tasks
 - taks_id (PK) 
 - project_id (FK)
```

The requirements are:

- Each Task belongs to only one project.
- Each Project has one or more users.
- Each Task has 0 or more users (but the users must belong to the project to which the task belongs to).

I'm currently trying to do the above with 2 join tables:

```
UsersProjects
[user_id]    INT           NOT NULL,
[project_id] INT           NOT NULL,
[accepted] BIT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY ([user_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[_Users] ([user_id]),
FOREIGN KEY ([project_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[_Projects] ([project_id]), 
CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersProjects] PRIMARY KEY ([user_id], [project_id])

UsersTasks
[user_id]    INT           NOT NULL,
[task_id] INT           NOT NULL,
[accepted] BIT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY ([user_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[_Users] ([user_id]),
FOREIGN KEY ([task_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[_Tasks] ([task_id]), 
CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersTasks] PRIMARY KEY ([user_id], [task_id])
```

Am I on the right track for the many-to-many relationships and for the requirements?
How can I optimise it?

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each Task has 0 or more users (but the users must belong to the project to which the task belongs to).

I assume you're asking how to enforce this last constraint - it's not there in your current DB schema. I see two options:

1. You have to do it via SQL (e.g. when you insert a record into UsersTasks you issue a SELECT on UsersProjects JOIN Tasks to see if there's at least record matching)
2. You change the structure of the Tasks Primary Key. I.e. you create a PK to be the compound (Project_ID + Task_ID) and Task_ID is then no longer an identity field but starts with e.g. 1 for each new Project. Then the PK for UsersTasks also becomes User_ID + Project_ID + Task_ID and then you can reference a completely FK straight to UserProjects (User_ID + Project_ID). It's less intuitive than Solution 1 but works and requires no custom SQL for enforcing integrity.

For Option 2:

Tasks has got a slightly different constraint

```
...
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tasks] PRIMARY KEY ([project_id], [task_id])

UsersTasks
[user_id]    INT           NOT NULL,
[project_id] INT        NOT NULL,
[task_id] INT           NOT NULL,
[accepted] BIT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY ([user_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[_Users] ([user_id]),
FOREIGN KEY ([project_id], [task_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[_Tasks] ([project_id],[task_id]), 
FOREIGN KEY ([user_id], [project_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[_User_Projects] ([user_id],[project_id]), 
CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersTasks] PRIMARY KEY ([user_id], [project_id], [task_id])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Would it be possible to give me the SQL statements for the above because I'm a bit new to SQL and I'm not sure I completely understand you (Solution 2).